# Are there any Packet Sniffing tools other than scapy in python?

Tags: python

Are there any  packet sniffing tools other than scapy in python3x that does the following:

1. sniff packets without being connected to a network
2. show packet structure, example fields/tags and their hex values (like that of wireshark or tshark or tcpdump?)

NB: I am operating in a linux environment.

Comment: Why not scapy? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am looking to sniff EAP packets, their structure and hex values..any suggestion..I tried using scapy command like "sniff(iface="mon0",prn=lambda x:x.show())" . this shows EAP packets summary..it does not show details such as if it is a message 1 or 3 or the hex value..

Comment: I notice the "load" values in EAP packets (when capturing with scapy) are hex characters..I was able I correspond these hex characters with the hex character of the EAP (captured in wireshark). I then look at the name of the fields in wireshark these hex characters represent...however..I am still curious if there are other tools like scapy in python that shows ALL field names and their hex values